# Redirection & SEO related stuff while moving to a new blog

Tags: seo, redirects, url, migration

I have a WordPress blog and recently I have setup a new blog lets call the old blog as *blog old* and new blog as *blog new*. What I did is moved the content, photos, pictures and all 250 posts from *blog old* to *blog new*. Both the blog name are changed as they are pointing to different domain names!

I read helpful things in this site itself at [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29148/how-can-i-move-redirect-single-blog-posts-from-one-blog-to-another).

I will no longer use *blog old*, moreover I am concerned about the SEO of the *blog new*. The *blog new* is fairly new (just 24 hours and no pages have been indexed in Google).

I have done the following stuff:

- Deleted all the post share at Facebook fan Page, Twitter profile, Google+ page and Finally deleted the fan page/Twitter, Google+ page.
- Edited the link backs of *old blog* in the *blog new*.

The question I have is:

1. How do I prevent duplicate content issues?
2. Do I go straightaway and delete all the posts in *blog old*?
3. Should I start sharing the blog posts in *blog new*?
4. Should I submit the new site to Webmaster Tools or wait for few
   weeks?

Every comment here is appreciated! What issues can I face relating to SEO?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use 301 redirect, this will all pass the old blog SEO power to new blog.

Also check out the following video for more details on domain name change.
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83106

Answer (score 0):

I use a wordpress plugin called Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin: http://www.fischercreativemedia.com/wordpress-plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/
It allows me to set up redirects per page as things are deleted or moved.  One you install it you get a "Redirect Options" menu in the dashboard.  Start deleting the posts in Old Blog and put in a redirect for each one.

Submit both the Blog Old and Blog New to Google webmaster tools.  Under "Configuration" -> "Change of Address" you can tell Google that you are moving websites.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prevent duplicate content issues by using 301 redirects from old blog to new blog.  There are a number of tools mentioned here and the Yoast SEO plugin will also do it.
2. No.  Leave it running with the redirects for as long as possible.
3. Yes, absolutely. As soon as New Blog is ready to be the primary destination, start using and sharing from it.
4. As soon as the redirects on Old Blog are set, submit new blog to GWT.